# Offline Windows Event ID Solution?

Tags: windows, windows-event-log, eventviewer

In my work i have many buildings with no internet , is there a program or an offline database for errors with event ID for Microsoft , so that will save my time for calling my assistants to search for the reason of a unique event Id .

I wish my question is clear for all , and may help others also .

Comment: What do you mean `offline` database? Something you can look up from the disconnected sites? Why don't you just look them up from your site?

Comment: @joeqwerty like a small program , contain all errors indications , because sometimes there is not internet

Comment: Use a tablet / smartphone with internet. Far easier.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - not really.  Slightly better answer - the only thing that is really comparable to this would be something like your company's own KB system, perhaps something like System Center Service Manager knowledge base articles.  A "Knowledge Management" system, for the ITIL-inclined.